# Trigger re-read(or update) of (System)App database

Tags: system-apps

System apps or apps in general are capable of storing information within a database. My problem is now: for example the Launcher app does store settings like the amount of apps and their position on the homescreen, widgets etc. into a database on the data partition.

These settings are usually just read from the database again even if there is a new Launcher app replacement with different settings for the homescreen.

My question is now: `Is there any method(via shell) to trigger an update or re-read of this apps database, so that the new values from the new Launcher replacement are taken into account without just deleting the whole database or messing around with the current database?`

Comment: Not sure, but even Lollipop's stock launcher and Google Now Launcher uses different database (or other data storage). So, unless you're sure both launchers use same database, then there might be a possibility to *update/overwrite the DB*, but it will come to effect when the launcher reads the DB again.

Comment: the launcher is just an example for better understanding what I actually mean. Iam talking in general about a method how to trigger such an update for the specific database of an app. The replaced apps are using the same package and are built from the same source just with different configurations.

Comment: Then, as long as the database file is there, the app will read it when it needs to read it. There is no need to force read/update from outside (well, I'm not even sure if it's possible). It should be controlled within the app itself. Apologize if I still couldn't grasp the idea, maybe other readers might have solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to archive the right answer from Andrew's comment:

> Then, as long as the database file is there, the app will read it when
>   it needs to read it. There is no need to force read/update from
>   outside (well, I'm not even sure if it's possible). It should be
>   controlled within the app itself. Apologize if I still couldn't grasp
>   the idea, maybe other readers might have solution for this.

I was confused about how these databases are handled. It is exactly as Andrew wrote: It depends on the actual implementation when and how the database is re-read.